# TrueStudio flashing board gives "Unknown MCU found on target error"

Tags: microcontroller, programming, programmer

I am attempting to flash a custom PCB using Atollic TrueStudio and a Nucleo board. I have the PCB connected to the SWD header on the Nucleo. In TrueStudio I have set the target device and am using ST-LINK as the debug probe with the GDB Connection Settings set to "Autostart local GDB server", and the Interface set to JTAG. When I click debug, it builds the project, but then gives me an error:

```
Target unknown MCU target

Error in initializing ST-Link device.
Reason: Unknown MCU found on target.
```

What does this error mean?

I have also tried debugging using the SWD interface, but when I use that I get the error:

```
Target no device found

Error in initializing ST-Link device.
Reason: No device found on target.
```

I have searched for explanations of these errors, but have not been able to find anything helpful. I have also looked through tutorials on using TrueStudio, but I have not been able to figure out why this fails to flash my board or what is going wrong.

Also, I am new to TrueStudio, so please explain. Thanks!

Comment: What does Atollic support say?

Comment: I am using the free version of TrueStudio and have not paid for Atollic's support.

Comment: You need to figure out what chip id it *is* detecting.  If something implausible like all 0's, you have a wiring issue with SWD or a design issue in the board or an assembly issue.  If something valid (try a web search on the value), perhaps you have a chip variant unknown to (potentially outdated versions of) the tools you are trying to use.  Do make sure you removed the jumpers that connect the on-board target to the Nucleo's SWD adapter, and make sure your target is connected to the correct header on the Nucleo, *not* where the jumpers were.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks for the comment. I have the ST-LINK jumpers removed and the target board is connected to the SWD header and I checked the wiring. Can you explain how I can find the chip id that it is detecting?

Comment: No idea for atollic, maybe some kind of verbose mode?  Or you could try ST's flashing tool for windows and see if it detects anything.  If you used openocd it would be printed to the console.

Comment: Do you mean that you're using the ST-Link on the Nucleo board to program the MCU on your custom board?  Did you remove the two jumpers on the Nucleo board that enable this ability?  Why did you select the JTAG interface instead of SWD?

Comment: Yes, I am using the ST-Link on the Nucleo board to program my MCU, and I removed the jumpers on the Nucleo. I have also tried the SWD interface, but it gives me the error: 
`Error in initializing St-Link device.
Reason: No device found on target`

Comment: You may have to open up a solder bridge (SB) associated with the NRST signal on the Nucleo board.  Check the Nucleo board's User Manual.

Comment: I inherited this project and the programmer before me had flashed the board before with this same setup (except that I had to re-wire the connection between the Nucleo SWD header and the board), so I am confident that the necessary solder bridges were removed. I think the issue has something to do with my configuration in TrueStudio, but being new to TrueStudio I am not entirely sure what I am missing.